# WPF Maintain Keyboard Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, focus

I'm creating a `UserControl` consisting of a `TextBox` and a `ListView`. I want keyboard focus to remain with the `TextBox` as long as the control has keyboard focus (selection changes in the `ListView` shouldn't remove keyboard focus from the `TextBox`).

I've tried catching `GotKeyboardFocus` in the `ListView` and passing keyboard focus back to the `TextBox` using `Keyboard.Focus(),` but this seems to cancel any selection operation in the `ListView`.  The below code shows the problem.  Does anyone know how to achieve this functionality?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" />
        <ListView x:Name="ListBox1" Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocus="ListBox1_GotKeyboardFocus">
            <ListViewItem Content="Able" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Baker" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Charlie" />
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListBox1_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Keyboard.Focus(TextBox1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's possible to change focus in the MouseUp event. I think if you do it too early, like in the GotKeyboardFocus event, you'll steal focus before the listview can handle the event and select the chosen item.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" />
    <ListView x:Name="ListBox1" MouseUp="ListBox1_MouseUp">
        <ListViewItem Content="Able" />
        <ListViewItem Content="Baker" />
        <ListViewItem Content="Charlie" />
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>

private void ListBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead, have you considered just capturing keystrokes and putting those keystrokes into your TextBox?

```
<Window PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" />
        <ListBox />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in your window's code-behind:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text += e.Key.ToString();
}
```

You'll have to do extra work for anything like special characters (backspace, etc), and obviously a Key handler for your "Enter" or "Post" operation, but it gives you the ability to just free-form type while the Window has focus and to properly handle the keystrokes as necessary.

Comment: I think that would work. I would like, however, to have the cursor stay in the TextBox. The functionality I'm shooting for is similar to IntelliSense in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling your WPF window from a WinForm you must use this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfWindow);
wpfWindow.show();
```

from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.enablemodelesskeyboardinterop.aspx).

Thats how I solved my keyboard problem.

IceX

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but what if instead of listening to the GotKeyboardFocus event, you listen to the SelectionChanged event on the ListBox?

Comment: I tried that. In that case, you can select from the ListView, but focus is removed from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Put Focusable=false on your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was driving me crazy. Even though set focus to `UserControl` every time lost focus, still couldn't get my command hot keys to work. All I had to do was to set the property `Focusable` to `true`, and voilà, it's working!